# In which order does a mongodump --query executes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodump

In which order does a mongodump --query executes, is from last insert to first insert or the other way around, if it is other way around is there any option that I can pass to mongodump --query, so that mongodump queries start from first insert to last insert,

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When mongodump runs (with a couple of exceptions) it will default to walking the `_id` index in ascending order.  This may be approximately the same as insert order if you are using the default `ObjectID` type in the `_id` field but it is not guaranteed.  The reason it is not guaranteed is because those default `_id` values are usually generated on the client side and you can insert any valid (unique) `ObjectID` you wish into the field.

One of the most common exceptions to this is dumping a capped collection (like the oplog) where there is no `_id` index (some may have them for replication, so this is not all capped collections).  In that case a tablescan will be done, so no guarantee of insert order because data can wrap around etc.